# how to use imagemagick c api to convert http stream image instead of file image

Tags: imagemagick

The imagemagick c api official examples show that all image data to be converted is read from file. How can I read image data from a http stream instead of file to convert?

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Most HTTP client API will have a write callback method. For example [libcurl](/questions/tagged/libcurl) has [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html).

You would be responsible for implementing a [c](/questions/tagged/c) method to collect the stream data into a buffer, and pass the buffer to ImageMagick on successful stream completion.

If the data stream is an image format (i.e. `GIF`, `JPEG`, `PNG`, &tc), you would invoke [`MagickReadImageBlob`](https://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickReadImageBlob) method.

```
MagickBooleanType MagickReadImageBlob(MagickWand *wand,
  const void *blob,const size_t length)
```

Now if the data stream is image data (RGBA pixels), then you would leverage [`MagickImportImagePixels`](https://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickImportImagePixels) method.

```
MagickBooleanType MagickImportImagePixels(MagickWand *wand,
  const ssize_t x,const ssize_t y,const size_t columns,
  const size_t rows,const char *map,const StorageType storage,
  const void *pixels)
```

*But remember!* If this is the case, you would also be responsible with knowning the images size (width + hight), data-storage type (char / float / long), and channel map (RGBA / BGRA / CMYK / HSL) *before* importing the data.

Comment: my version is 7.0.6-1 on osx

Comment: the official examples use this: `MagickCoreGenesis(*argv, MagickTrue);` to initial magick environment. The *argv is the image file path. The problem is when I convert http sream data, how can I initial the environment?

Comment: The `*argv` should be the same value from the entrance `main` function. It's needed to ensure that the executable is accessible, and sets the client name & path. Nothing to do with image file path, or data streams.